# Creating a Set of Arrays

Tags: ruby

I have a collection (in my case, Array, but it could be any Enumerable) of Arrays of Strings, such as

```
@collection = [%w(ab cd ef), %w(xx yy zz), %w(ab cd ef)]
```

and I want to remove the different ones.  I'm interested in the difference in value, not in object identity. The naive approach would be to create a Set like this:

```
@different = Set.new(@collection)
```

I will access this Set frequently, by checking something like

```
if @different.member?(%w(x1 x2 x3))
```

Since Hashes (and consequently Sets) in Ruby are optimized to work with Strings as a key, I fear that using Arrays as keys could be pretty inefficient, and I wonder whether there is an alternative approach.

In my concrete case, it is ensured that all arrays involved have the same number of elements, and all the strings are made out of letters and digits only, so instead of using the arrays themselves as elements, I could store their string representation, say

```
@different = Set.new(@collection.map {|arr| arr.join(';')})
```

However, this causes now of course the overhead of doing a `join` and a `split` to convert forth and back between arrays and their corresponding strings.

Does anybody have an alternative approach, or should I better stick with my original design, which is at least easier to understand.

Comment: By "different" do you mean unique?

Comment: _"Array as keys could be pretty inefficient"_ – don't optimize "just in case". Make sure that your array keys are in fact slower than e.g. strings.

Comment: I would imagine that `array.hash` combines the hash values of its elements. In fact, any approach you take would need to produce the same hash code in case the contents of the array are equal, so at a minimum would need to iterate over the key. That is to say, i don't see any other "better" approach than simply using array as key

Comment: Did you actually benchmark if array keys are significantly slower than string keys (with the constraint that array.join.length == string.length)?

Comment: @pjs: Yes. "unique" would be correct.